# Trying to install django-haystack

Tags: python, django, debian, django-haystack

Hello I'm trying to install `django-haystack` on a Debian 7 x86 but it is **impossible** to install, this Debian is fresh installation, I compiled python 3.6, I am little disappointed, this the error I get

```
 100% |ââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââ| 389kB 9.0kB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools_scm/: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/setuptools-scm/: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'setuptools_scm' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno -2] Name or service not known -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or working download links found for setuptools_scm
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-sc1wwqz8/django-haystack/setup.py", line 68, in <module>
        setup_requires=['setuptools_scm'],
      File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.6.1/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/root/cubapk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 315, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/root/cubapk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/root/cubapk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 850, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/root/cubapk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1122, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/root/cubapk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1134, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/root/cubapk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 429, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/root/cubapk/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 659, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('setuptools_scm')
```

Comment: Upgrade your `pip` with `pip install pip --upgrade`

Comment: so sorry  @RaminNietzsche this did not help me, I am keeping in same trouble

Answer (score 3):

@RaminNietzsche, after few days I figured out the way out to fix this trouble, what did was to install by hand this `setuptools_scm`, I do not know why pip did not find any suitable distribution as the error message say.

What I did was this:

`pip install setuptools_scm`

Answer (score 1):

Take another look at the OSError: `Name or service not known`.

This means your fresh install didn't have a proper resolver yet. Probably fixed itself a few days later, because you fixed your resolver.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was seeing the following error:

```
Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('setuptools_scm<4,>=3.2')
```

I tried to run `pip install setuptools_scm` but it didn't work as package was already installed.

What worked for me is installing the exact version `setuptools_scm` is asking.

```
pip install setuptools_scm==3.2
```