# Django cannot install Django-Oscar

Tags: python, django, django-haystack, django-oscar, django-errors

I'm trying to install `django-oscar`, after spending couple hours, and upgraded my `pip`, and also `setuptools`, the error is still not going away, I can `pip install` other packages such as `spirit`, but just cannot install Oscar, following is the error message,

Thanks a mill!
Jim

```
Using cached django-haystack-2.8.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Couldn't find index page for 'setuptools_scm' (maybe misspelled?)
    No local packages or working download links found for setuptools_scm
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/bm/ghr3m2px1d76gsgd7vkbh5yr0000gn/T/pip-install-LXpkON/django-haystack/setup.py", line 71, in <module>
        setup_requires=['setuptools_scm'],
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 128, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 123, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 513, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 774, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1057, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1069, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 580, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 667, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('setuptools_scm')

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/bm/ghr3m2px1d76gsgd7vkbh5yr0000gn/T/pip-install-LXpkON/django-haystack/
```

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44662881/trying-to-install-django-haystack & https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1571

Comment: try running `pip install setuptools_scm` individually to see what happens?